# To center align a fixed top menu in html page

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simpl web page where I use a menu bar in a `div` tag . When I am not fixing the `div` tag it can be aligned in center using:

```
.top .overlay{
 background-image:none;
 text-align:center;
}
```

But when I use the `position: fixed;` then the alignment of menu doesn't work

```
.top .overlay{
 background-image:none;
 position:fixed;
 text-align:center;
}
```

It's working if I use a fixed margin, but the problem is that the behavior would change depending on the screen resolution.

please help

Comment: Two choices here: **A)** please rephrase your question. **B)** please provide a demo in which the issue is obvious.

Comment: http://alok.net23.net/brain2012/

Comment: here in css file .top .overlay{
 background-image:none;
 text-align:center;
}

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.top .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And don't forget to remove the `margin-left: 18%;` part.

Comment: .top .overlay{
 background-image:none;
  position:fixed;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  width="100%";
}            but not working

Comment: @Alok Not `width="100%"`, it should be `width: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `margin:0 auto;` in `.top .overlay {}`

```
  .top .overlay{
background-image:none;
position:fixed;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thanx every body i got the idea of width .top .overlay{
 background-image:none;
  position:fixed;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Solution for you: set `width` to 100%

.top .overlay{
  ...
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  ...
}

Answer (score 0):

I tried this CSS on your site with firebug and it worked:

```
.top .overlay {
    background-image: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 830px;
}
```

The `auto` value for the `margin` CSS property will work only if a `width` is set.
I also removed the `position` property.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
    position :fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top:0%;
    width: *AS_REQUIRED* px;
}

#container p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

As shown above i have created two divisions:

1. *For Positioning menu and its design*
2. *For text inside the menu*

***NOTE***: text will be aligned center when you write text inside the `<p> </p>` tag